# How can I wrap the table trs with divs on rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view, html-table, partial

**view:**
    `<table><%= render(:partial => 'item') %></table>`

**the partial:**
    `<div><tr><td>foo</td></tr></div>`

**I'm expecting to see:**
    `<table><div><tr><td>foo</td></tr></div></table>`

**but I'm seeing:**
    `<div></div>
    <table><tr><td>foo</td></tr></table>`

**why? and how to achieve my expectation?**

Comment: it would be easier if you show your code.

Comment: write table in partial file like <table> <div><tr><td>foo</td></tr></div> </table> and in view <%= render(:partial => 'item') %>

Comment: Why do you want `<div>`'s around `<tr>`'s? Is that valid markup?

Comment: you need to do <div><table><tr><td>foo</td></tr></table></div> in partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping tds and trs in divs is incorrect. If you want to add some css or mark a particular td for Capybara, you can use the id or class property **inside** the td. Something like `<td id="td_id" class="td_class">`.

Answer (score 0):

Erb won't generate what you are expecting because that is incorrect html. You cannot have your trs or tds wrapped in divs. In fact, trs can only be either direct children of the table element or direct children of tbody (html5).

Why do you want to wrap trs in divs anyway?